# Line chart is not shoing properly data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, charts, linechart

I am using the Charts library for displaying a line chart in my app

However, the chart is not displaying correctly when there are only three points available

See the attached screenshots below. Thanks in advance.

[I want this type of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzv7Y.jpg)

[but results get this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMiLE.png)

See Below my code for reference

I am using this library:-
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

```
        chartView?.invalidate()
        chartView?.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
        chartView?.description?.isEnabled = false
        chartView?.setTouchEnabled(true)
        chartView?.isDragEnabled = true
        chartView?.setScaleEnabled(false)
        chartView?.setPinchZoom(false)
        chartView?.setDrawGridBackground(false)
        chartView?.maxHighlightDistance = 300f
        val x: XAxis? = chartView?.xAxis
        x?.isEnabled = Valse

        val y = chartView?.axisLeft
        y?.setLabelCount(0, false)
        y?.isEnabled = false
        y?.textColor = Color.GRAY
        y?.setDrawGridLines(false)
        y?.axisLineColor = Color.BLACK
        chartView?.axisLeft?.axisMinimum = 0f
        chartView?.axisRight?.axisMinimum = 0f

        chartView?.axisRight?.isEnabled = false

        chartView?.legend?.isEnabled = false

        val values = ArrayList<Entry>()
        values.add(Entry(0f, 4836.62f))
        values.add(Entry(1f, 4856.41f))
        values.add(Entry(2f, 4940.18f))

        val set1: LineDataSet

        if (chartView?.data != null &&
            chartView.data!!.dataSetCount > 0
        ) {
            set1 = chartView.data.getDataSetByIndex(0) as LineDataSet
            set1.values = values
            chartView.data.notifyDataChanged()
            chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
            chartView.invalidate()
        } else {
            // create a dataset and give it a type
            set1 = LineDataSet(values, "")
            set1.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
            set1.cubicIntensity = 0.2f
            set1.setDrawFilled(false)
            set1.setDrawCircles(false)
            set1.lineWidth = 1.5f
            set1.color = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorPrimary)
            indexValue?.text = arrIndexList?.last()?.indexValue.toString()
            change?.text = arrIndexList?.last()?.change.toString()
            changePercent?.text = arrIndexList?.last()?.changePercent.toString()

        
            val data = LineData(set1)
            data.setValueTextSize(9f)
            data.setDrawValues(false)
            chartView?.data = data
            chartView?.animateX(1500)
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "not displaying correctly"? You're adding `4836.62`, `4856.41` and `4940.18` as values, which is increasing, so the chart looks correct to me

Comment: I am also trying descending value not still not working on my end, but this (4836.62, 4856.41 and 4940.18) perfectly working on ios